# Adding PIVOT'ed values when not sure how many records I have to pivot with

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm working with an off the shelf reporting tool that can take T-SQL statements to return data in exactly the same way as you would with SQL Server. As such however I am slightly restricted in generating the reports as it has to be through this interface, no custom web control allowed.

I have two tables [Client], [Related Clients]:

[Client] - GUID, other fields like name etc. 
[Related Clients] - GUID, FK to GUID in Client, other fields like name

The requirement is to output the data from these two tables conjoined to match their old reports. However from what I understand, their old data structure was more like:

[Client] - , RelatedClient1Name, RelatedClient2Name, RelatedClient3Name ... RelatedClient[N]Name

My knowledge of SQL unfortunately fails me here, I believe I need to: 
 
a) pivot the values in Related Clients and 
b) populate fields RelatedClient[N]Name but have to take into account that the result set will then have things where for example, there's 5 related clients for on client but the others have say only 4 so there's a RelatedClient5Name field that's empty for all the others.

If I was coding this in .NET, I would be using two datatables which I could then merge into a new one but as this has to be done via this interface, that's not an option. However, from my understanding this would likely involve cursors and temporary tables which I believe are frowned upon for their overhead costs.

Fortunately the business rules say that only a maximum of 9 Related Clients can be allowed per Client record so it's not completely necessary to generate for completely countless.

Comment: What reporting tool are you using?  Usually the reporting tool handles the pivoting of you data rather than your SQL code

Comment: It's one built into a CMS. I believe it was designed more for handling the output, leaving the developer to do the logic so you basically point your result set at different output types like graphs, table or simply output a CSV/xlsx/XML file so it's not got any sql development tools to it.

Comment: You don't need SQL development tools, you need presentation tools.  You say it can create charts and tables; can it not create a pivot table in a similar way that you would within Excel or SSRS?

Comment: It can't, it's literally acts like a cutdown datagrid; give it a datasource to read from and it just displays, there's no configuration available there except which field to read x/y values for for graphs or colours etc.
Similarly because this will be a merge of two tables, it needs to happen before the databind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can get you started. you basically need to use CTE to group the client into RowVal (1, 2, 3... etc) and then use a left join to link it back to the client table. I have done a mock up with only 2 related client. You just have to add more joins.

```
DECLARE @Client  table (CGUIDx  int, FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20))
insert into @Client
select 1, 'Theresa', 'May' union all
select 2, 'David', 'Cameron' union all
select 3, 'Gordon', 'Brown' union all
select 4, 'Tony', 'Blair' union all
select 5, 'John', 'Major' union all
select 6, 'Margaret', 'Thatcher' union all
select 7, 'James', 'Callaghan' union all
select 8, 'Harold', 'Wilson'

-- FK to GUID  is ClientId
DECLARE @RelatedClients  table (RGUIDx  int, ClientId int, RFirstName varchar(20), RLastName varchar(20))
insert into @RelatedClients
select 1, 1, 'James', 'Brown' union all
select 2, 1, 'Michael', 'Jackson' union all
select 3, 2, 'Lawrence', 'Okezue' union all
select 4, 3, 'Okpo', 'Utuh'

; with rClient as (

select *, RowVal=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY RGUIDx)
from
@RelatedClients c

)



SELECT c.*,
    RelatedClient1Name=r1.RFirstName,
    RelatedClient2Name=r2.RFirstName 
FROM
    @Client c

    left join rClient r1 on
        r1.ClientId=c.CGUIDx 
        and
        r1.RowVal=1

    left join rClient r2 on
        r2.ClientId=c.CGUIDx 
        and
        r2.RowVal=2
```